# How to include Internet Permission in Kivy? (Android 6)

Tags: android, permissions, kivy, urllib2, buildozer

I want to use the standard Python module `urllib2` in my Kivy App which requires access to the Internet. But when I uncomment `#android.permissions = INTERNET`
and package the App the App doesn't inform me about the Internet Permission while installing the .apk and when I'm using `urllib2` my App crashes (probably because no Internet Permission)

Thx in advance!

Comment: Uncommenting the permissions line should be fine. Use `adb logcat` to find the actual problem.

Comment: Actually I've forggoten to enable Wifi on my tablet. You have to use `try` and  `except` to avoid a crash in Kivy because of no Internet

Answer (score 1):

In this case the modification is not made in the python code but in the buildozer.spec file.

Inside this file on line 87 you will find *"# (list) Permissions"* on the line below it will have *"# android.permissions = INTERNET"* uncomment this line so that the app has internet access permission, if you don't find the line you can copy and paste *"android.permissions = INTERNET"*, this way the apk will be able to connect to the internet, but it may end up with a certificate error *"SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error"*, in this case do the following:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

that way the error will be resolved.